# Best way of loading custom cells from a XIB

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an app, and I'd need custom UITableViewCells, I've been trying different ways, but no one works for what I want, or simply don't work. Can someone guide me how can I do it? Actually the cell, needs to have some UIImageViews and an UILabel and a UITextView. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a NIB file with a single `UITableViewCell` in it.

Loading the cell from the nib is a two liner:

```
NSArray* objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TheFile" 
                                                 owner:nil
                                               options:nil];
UITableViewCell* cell = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
```

This method will allways access disk when used, so it can be slow. On iOS 4 and later the is a better help class that caches the NIB in memory, for faster creation. Use like this:

```
// Cache this one!
UINib* nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TheFile" bundle:nil];

// Then do:
NSArray* objects = [nib instantiateWithOwner:nil
                                     options:nil];
UITableViewCell* cell = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Really good :D but do you know how can I add UIImageViews? Shall I create them programatically and use addSubview:?

Comment: @zad0xsis - Does not drag and drop in Interface Builder work for you?

Comment: But now I get `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x61a9de0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key useravatar.'` while trying to get outlets working

Comment: @zad0xis - Have you set the correct class for the cell in the identity tab?